Coloring lines in Gnuplot 5.4 when using parallelaxes
I'm trying to create a parallelaxes plots in Gnuplot, but I can't figure out how to color the lines in the plot.
There are several tutorials online but as of Gnuplot 5.4 the syntax of the parallelaxes command was changed and these are now obsolete. The final line of my script currently looks like this:plot for [col=1:5] "data.dat" using col with parallelaxes and generates the plot below. What I would like to do is to color each line depending on whether it passes through the shirt or jeans tick on the second axis.
Using the old syntax the above mentioned line would look something akin to ṕlot "data.dat" using 1:2:3:4:2 linecolour variable. The final :2 assigns which column should be used to define to color of each line. As you can see, the syntax has changed. I would use an older version but these seem to be limited to 4 axes, which is not enough for my case.
.

Please always provide some minimal data for testing.

It is hard to answer confidently without having your data file to test against, but assuming that the shirt/jeans entries are numerical values, e.g. 3 for a shirt and 14 for a pair of jeans, I think the answer would be something like this
set style data parallelaxes
plot for [col=1:5] "data.dat" using col:2 lc variable

Only the color associated with the first plot clause (parallel axis 1) is used, so perhaps it would be clearer to write this
plot "data.dat" using 1:2 lc variable, for [col=2:5] "" using col

That assumes that you are OK with whatever line color the numerical value in column 2 represents.  If you want to define your own color categories, something like this would assign linecolor 2 to the "shirt" value, linecolor 1 to the "jeans" value, and linecolor 0 to anything else found in that column.
$DATA << EOD
10 10 26 12 13
6  10 28 13 13
10  7 30 14 10
6   7 32 15 16
EOD

jeans = 10
shirt =  7
color(item) = (item == jeans) ? 1 : (item == shirt) ? 2 : 0
set style data parallelaxes
set border 0
unset tics; unset key
set for [i=1:5] paxis i tics 2
set for [i=1:5] paxis i range [0:25]
set paxis 3 range [24:36]

plot $DATA using 1:(color(int($2))) lc variable, for [col=2:5] "" using col


